# How to avoid component rerendering when route change which similar to keep-alive in vuejs?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, router

is there something in react which similar to keep-alive in vuejs?
I do not want to rerender pages when route changes,can anyone help me?

Comment: is there someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that react doesn't support the similar feature `keep-alive`. We need to implement it by ourselves.

According to the [source code of `keep-alive`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/1049461c073ea944f45740efa717b176bfc06458/src/core/components/keep-alive.js) component of vue, we need to cache the virtual dom (`vnode` in vue) of children in state. The `keep-alive` component is the wrapper of router, thus the cache will never be pruned when router changed.

In addition, I have a simple approach in my app, if you don't care about 
the performance. The main idea is to hide/show the view component on router changing event, instead of mount/unmount.

```
<Router>
  <Layout>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/foo" component={Foo} />
      <Route path="/bar" component={Bar} />
    </Switch>
    // the alive route match any path so that it will be never rerendered
    <Route path="/:any" component={AliveComponent} />
  <Layout>
</Router>
```

Codes in `AliveComponent`:

```
...
state = {isShown: false};
componentWillMount () {
  const {history, location} = this.props;
  this.setState({isShown: location.pathname === '/alive-view-path'});

  const unlistenHistory = history.listen(
    ({pathname, state}, action) => {
      this.setState({isShown: pathname === '/alive-view-path'});
    }
  );
  this.setState({unlistenHistory});
}
componentWillUnmount () {
  if (_.isFunction(this.state.unlistenHistory)) {
    this.state.unlistenHistory();
  }
}
render () {
  return <div style={{display: this.state.isShown ? 'block' : 'none'}} />
}
...
```